# Why do I get untrusted certificate error for Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl, browser-support

I face this error only in Google Chrome (version 33.0.1750.146 m), not in Firefox on the same system.

Because of the problem I couldn't sign in to my account and I don't face this error with other SSL sites.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is because HTTPS is not fully implemented yet and hence unsupported.

There are issues with the format of the meta URLs and getting a sensible number of certificates. Once these are resolved *then* HTTPS will be officially supported.

Comment: so its a bug from stackoverflow.

Comment: Well, not anymore.

Comment: @Braiam this was from four years ago. It seems pointless to comment. Arguably it was pointless editing too (I know you didn't do the edit)

Comment: The only reason why this was active was because Adam edited it to add an status complete tag on the question. Arguably, an answer should have been written at that time, or maybe closing as duplicate if there's a question that asks for the same. Point being, nothing is ever pointless if we make the situation better, and having updated information is better.